# Big O notation of an algorithm with a matrix as an input

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

So over the years, after working with algorithms I came across a question regarding the asymptotic behaviour of an algorithms.

In mathematics, one could define Big-W(hatever) as "The asymptotic behaviour of f(n) measured against the input size 'n'." The definition of Big-O that comes to my mind is (paraphrasing):

`In order for f(n) to be O(g(n)) we need to find a constant that multiplied by g(n) the expression 'f(n) < c*g(n)' from an initial input (i.e. n0) and forever.`

As we can see, everything is measured according to 'n' (the input).

My question is, if the input size of an algorithm is a matrix (by itself its already squared), does it mean that if I use two nested 'for' loops to traverse it, the algorithm still behaves as a O(n) algorithm?.

example:

```
1 1 1 1 0 1
2 2 0 2 1 0
3 3 1 3 2 1
0 4 2 4 3 2
1 5 3 5 4 0
2 6 0 6 5 1

for(var row=0; row<matrix.rows; row++){
    ...
    for(var col=0; col<matrix.columns; col++){
        ...
    }
}
```

My logic tells me that this is a O(n^2) but mathematics are very specific and the behaviour is measured according to the input size. So it is fine if this is O(n^2). But what confuses me is that if we look at the problem from a different perspective, it gets all messed up for me: if I were to only traverse the rows, this now looks like the algorithm's input is cols*rows (a matrix) and as I'm only traversing the rows, one could say that it behaves as an O(log(n)).

Can someone explain how something like this work? Will it be O(n) or O(n^2)? Is it the same for different dimensions (i.e. cubes, etc.)?

P.S. I hope I explained myself correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really an expert, but as far as I know, it is an O(n) algorithm, if that is your input.

You have exactly n^2 elements in your input and you are processing each element only once.

One should be careful while deciding the input size to find out algorithmic complexity. I will give you a more subtle example.

You are asked to find out whether a given number 'n' is prime or not. You write a naive algorithm to check for divisibility from 1 to n-1. Now, you can argue that you are doing only n operations, so it is a O(n) algorithm. However, in fact, this algorithm is exponential. The reason is, here your input is NOT of size 'n', but a single value which is represented by log n  bits. So, you input size is log n. Now, you are performing n operations. So, The relationship between your algorithm's number of operations and input size is exponential (since n = 2^(log n)).

The distinguishing idea here is what you mean by an operation (since you want count number of operations per input value). You could always argue that you input is just a matrix, you want to treat it as a single element, and thus your algorithm is O(1). However, this is not the case. The definition of an operation in the complexity context says that it should happen in constant time every time you perform it on a unit of input. However, you cannot claim your matrix operations happen in constant time because yous so called one element (matrix) is of variable size and multiplication can vary largely without bounds. Compare this to multiplication of integers, computers have specialized hardware for doing multiplication and there is  guarantee (up to a certain tolerance) on the upper bound on time taken for multiplication of integers, which is not a function of the integer's value.